# Booting Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 6.2.0-26 results in a kernel panic

Tags: boot, kernel, 22.04

I am running kernel 5.19.0-50-generic, meanwhile when start booting using new kernel 6.2.0-26-generic results in a kernel panic.

[image: kernel panic screenshot]

I'm not sure why.

We are using mainlines kernel to maintenance the kernels. Also if we try to remove kernel 6.2.0-26-generic it also failed.

[image: mainlines kernel screenshot]

Here is file under `/boot` folder:

```
@komp:/boot$ ls
config-5.19.0-50-generic      initrd.img.old                vmlinuz
config-6.2.0-26-generic       memtest86+.bin                vmlinuz-5.19.0-50-generic
efi                           memtest86+.elf                vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic
grub                          memtest86+_multiboot.bin      vmlinuz.old
initrd.img                    System.map-5.19.0-50-generic
initrd.img-5.19.0-50-generic  System.map-6.2.0-26-generic
```

Here I am trying to install nodejs, but there is an error related to kernel 6.2.0-26 (meanwhile right now it's running under kernel 5.19.0-50-generic).

```
komp:~$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (18.17.1-deb-1nodesource1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfreerdp-client2-2 libfreerdp-server2-2 libfreerdp2-2 libjs-highlight.js libvncserver1
  libwinpr2-2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 296 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic (6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-50-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fuse failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-50-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic (6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-26-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fuse failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i suspect about this error:

```
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fuse failed with return 1.
```

how do we fix this? appreciate your help.